# Quote Identification - Where does Luthor say this?

Tags: dc, episode-identification, lex-luthor

I'm trying to think of a famous Lex Luthor quote and what story he said it in.

> If I die, you die first

I know it was a movie or animated series, but I'm not sure which.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple google search reveals that it's a quote from [All-Star Superman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-Star_Superman_(film)) (2011) described by wikipedia as *"a direct-to-video animated superhero film based on the acclaimed comic book series of the same name by Grant Morrison and Frank Quitely.*"

---

> **Luthor:** *That's not why I used the gravity gun, I--*
>
> **Superman:** *No.*
>
> **Luthor:** *If I die, you die first.*